# Django render or redirect not working in view after AJAX POST

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using navigator.geolocation to get an update on location with it's provided watchPosition function with following code:

```
function updatePosition() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(calculateDistance);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
        }
    }
```

If then new location coordinates I fetch is under a kilometer in distance, I issue a post request and try to render another view. I use google maps API to calculate the distance with function computeDistanceBetween. Here is the code:

```
function calculateDistance(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var dis = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos, mapOptions.center);
       
        if(dis <= 1000 && dis >= 0 && rendered == false) {
         
            var url = '/app/near_park/';
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                    in_proximity : 1
                },
                success: function() {
                rendered = true;
                console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    console.log(xhr.status+": "+xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is the view handling the post request:

```
def index_close(request):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        current = Owner.objects.get(user=u)
        context_dict['checked_in'] = current.checked_in
    except:
        context_dict['checked_in'] = False
    print("##########")

#return redirect(reverse('app:register'))
    return render(request, 'app/index_close.html', context=context_dict)
```

Whenever I get a location update using the sensor utility of dev tools, I do see the print of hash marks on terminal but the redirect or render both do not work. The problem is not the index_close.html because I tried already existing and working html's also . None worked. The problem is this freaking render or redirect line that does not work. I have read numerous posts and solutions to similar problems but none worked for me. Can anybody spot the problem?

I have many POST requests and all redirect or render the html , I have a full working app. I was just adding this new feature to dynamically render new UI on location update via AJAX Post request, but it does not work.

Comment: If you use AJAX, the browser will not process the response, hence it will not render the result at the browser side or redirect it to a different URL. You can process the result in the `success` function.

Comment: But, I already have one view handling both get and post request and calling render successfully. It is the registeration page. Get request renders the form using template. Then post uses same template but different contents(Just a thank you message in p html tag) upon registering successfully. I do not understand why render on POST should not work for this view/scenario.

Comment: It works when I add in window.location in the success callback of POST. But, the problem is it keeps refreshing like every second. I though adding the rendered = True flag will stop the POST request to hit again and hence refresh but it is somehow refreshing again and again

Comment: nomally browser send request to server and get response from server, and it automatically replace all HTML on page (render it). But when you use AJAX then browser send request, get response from server but it doesn't replace HTML on page - and you can decide what to do with response. you can replace all HTML in browser or you can replace some part (if you get some part of dsata from server) but you have to write JavaScript code for this. If you use `window.location` then you get the same result as without AJAX - so you don't need it. AJAX was created to get part of data from server and replace

Comment: if you want to use AJAX then better create new function on server which gives only this part which you want replace on current page - it can be HTML or JSON data - and then you have to add code which put this data in correct place in current HTML.